# scripts/Kconfig.include:39: compiler 'i386-linux-gcc' not found

Tags: kernel, make

After running the following command

```
make ARCH=i386 CROSS_COMPILE=i386-linux- menuconfig
```

I get the error specified above.
What is the implication and what are the possible solves?

**What am I trying to do?**
I'm trying to access Kernel's configuration menu and make some configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to access configuration options for a specific architecture, you don’t need to specify a cross-compiler:

```
make ARCH=i386 menuconfig
```

If you want to build anything, you’ll need a valid cross-compiler, with the appropriate prefix. For example on Debian, you’d install the `gcc-i686-linux-gnu` package, and specify `ARCH=i386 CROSS_COMPILE=i686-linux-gnu-`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I gained access to the configuration options. and I now know what is required to build something